# Using TWS-BS-6 and RWS-374-3 for analog audio transmission?

Tags: rf, ham-radio

I'm really new to electronics and thought I'd build a simple walkie-talkie as a hobby and education project.  A friend suggested I consider using the TWS-BS-6 and RWS-374-3 for the radio transmission and reception.  But when I looked at the specification sheets here:

https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/General/TWS-BS-6_315MHz_ASK_RF_Transmitter_Module_Data_Sheet.pdf

https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/General/RWS-374-3_315MHz_ASK_RF_Receiver_Module_Data_Sheet.pdf

There doesn't appear to be analog input or output pins on these boards.  I see digital input/output pins though.  If I were to use them, do I need to consider the use of analog to digital converters and digital to analog converters as well?  I want to make sure I'm not reading these data sheets incorrectly.

Comment: The receiver has a linear output pin and so this is half the battle and, you may be lucky in that the transmitter will take a linear input on its digital in pin. But, these are really cheap squalid gadgets and provide very little user information in the data sheets.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I haven't had any luck receiving a signal on the linear output pin.  My audio circuits produces the signals I expect when connecting to other electronic components.  Is there another pair of FM transmitter/receiver pair you can suggest for analog audio transmission that are roughly as affordable?